# Name of this google service

Tags: api, web-services

I need to implement sports results in my application, google has its soccer results service

It is possible to use this service for general use, if that is what it is called, all the information about it I thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, google dont have an public api for that.
An alternative would be apis like:

- [newsapi](https://newsapi.org/s/google-news-api)
- [bloomberg news api](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/)
- [espn api](http://www.espn.com/apis/devcenter/docs/)